# Jquery scripts not working on Partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an index page that shows a partial page (let's call it partial A) via ajax call in a div on the same index page. At the end of the partial A view I have two dropdownlists and two buttons for which I wrote scripts in the partial view A but the script on partial view A is not running.
I have googled the problem where they say to put @render sections which I don't understand, hence my call for help here.
 I am using asp.net mvc with C#.

Thank you so much!

Comment: can you please show us the code ?

Comment: Yes just need to know how to do that... since I cannot add it in comments

Comment: edit your question and add your code please